# Google Cloud Folders with Permission Denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, easy-engine

I'm having this permissions issue on a setup I did on Google Cloud using Easy Engine.

The error is this: rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com: permission denied

I do not know why this happens, I have other sites on Vultr and Digital Ocean and I have not had this problem.

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should active su to have root access permissions.

try:

```
sudo su -
rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com
```